# How to call an explicitly implemented interface-method on the base class

Tags: c#, interface, base-class, explicit-implementation

I have a situation, where two classes (one deriving from the other) both implement the same interface explicitly:

```
interface I
{
  int M();
}

class A : I
{
  int I.M() { return 1; }
}

class B : A, I
{
  int I.M() { return 2; }
}
```

From the derived class' implementation of `I.M()`, I'd like to call the implementation of the base class, but I don't see how to do it. What I tried so far is this (in class B):

```
int I.M() { return (base as I).M() + 2; }
// this gives a compile-time error
//error CS0175: Use of keyword 'base' is not valid in this context

int I.M() { return ((this as A) as I).M() + 2; }
// this results in an endless loop, since it calls B's implementation
```

Is there a way to do this, without having to implement another (non interface-explicit)  helper method?

---

**Update**:

I know it's possible with a "helper" method which can be called by the derived class, e.g:

```
class A : I
{
    int I.M() { return M2(); }
    protected int M2 { return 1; }
}
```

I can also change it to implement the interface non-explicitly. But I was just wondering if it's possible without any of these workarounds.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Unfortunately, it isn't possible.**
Not even with a helper method. The helper method has the same problems as your second attempt: `this` is of type `B`, even in the base class and will call the implementation of `M` in `B`:

```
interface I
{
  int M();
}
class A : I
{
  int I.M() { return 1; }
  protected int CallM() { return (this as I).M(); }
}
class B : A, I
{
  int I.M() { return CallM(); }
}
```

The only workaround would be a helper method in `A` that is used in `A`'s implementation of `M`:

```
interface I
{
  int M();
}
class A : I
{
  int I.M() { return CallM(); }
  protected int CallM() { return 1; }
}
class B : A, I
{
  int I.M() { return CallM(); }
}
```

But you would need to provide a method like this also for `B` if there will be a `class C : B, I`...

Comment: Yes that workaround is what I have added to the updated question. But it's not what I wanted to know.

Comment: @M4N: That is just to make the answer a bit bigger ;-) The real answer is the first sentence: It is impossible without such workarounds.

Comment: To add to why it's impossible: Explicitly implemented interface methods are made private - making them impossible to call from a derived class. You should probably prefer a different method like the one Daniel listed anyway, to avoid the *call super* code smell.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why it is impossible, I understand now.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Thanks for the post, this saved me some time.

Answer (score 11):

**It is possible using reflection.**

The code follows. I added caching as a basic optimization, but it can be optimized further by using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` on `methodInfo`. Also, parameter count and type checks can be added using `methodInfo.GetParameters()`.

```
interface I   
{   
    int M();   
} 

class A : I   
{   
    int I.M() { return 1; }   
} 

class B : A, I   
{   
    BaseClassExplicitInterfaceInvoker<B> invoker = new BaseClassExplicitInterfaceInvoker<B>();
    int I.M() { return invoker.Invoke<int>(this, "M") + 2; }   
}

public class BaseClassExplicitInterfaceInvoker<T>
{
    private Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> cache = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>();
    private Type baseType = typeof(T).BaseType;

    private MethodInfo FindMethod(string methodName)
    {
        MethodInfo method = null;
        if (!cache.TryGetValue(methodName, out method))
        {
            var methods = baseType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

            foreach (var methodInfo in methods)
            {
                if (methodInfo.IsFinal && methodInfo.IsPrivate) //explicit interface implementation
                {
                    if (methodInfo.Name == methodName || methodInfo.Name.EndsWith("." + methodName))
                    {
                        method = methodInfo;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }   

            cache.Add(methodName, method);
        }

        return method;
    }

    public RT Invoke<RT>(T obj, string methodName)
    {            
        MethodInfo method = FindMethod(methodName);
        return (RT)method.Invoke(obj, null);
    }

}   //public static class BaseClassExplicitInterfaceInvoker<T>
```

[Here](http://osherove.com/blog/2008/10/15/use-reflection-to-find-methods-that-implement-explicit-inter.html) is the source of my inspiration.

Comment: Works like a charm. Reflection is the way to go in this case.

Comment: Just because you should probably consider not doing something does not mean there aren't instances where doing it is indispensable ;-) @Roland, thanks for sharing, works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

it is necessary explicitly?... Can you use an abstract class or class instead of interface?

```
interface ISample {}
class A : ISample {}
class B : A {}
...
base.fun();
...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce(v=vs.71).aspx

I have no idea its not possible call base method when it comes from implementation of interface.

Comment: No! B has a different implementation of the interface than A (it adds something to A's implementation).

Comment: @M4N - Then you can only extend A override the method and make a base call to the method and continue implementing the method.

Comment: See updated question. (explicit implementation is not necessary, but I was just wondering whether it's possible)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace SampleTest
{
    interface IInterface1
    {
        void Run();
    }

    interface IInterface2
    {
        void Run();
    }

    public class BaseClass : IInterface1, IInterface2
    {
        public void Interface1Run()
        {
            (this as IInterface1).Run();
        }

        public void Interface2Run()
        {
            (this as IInterface2).Run();
        }

        void IInterface2.Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am from interface 2");
        }

        void IInterface1.Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am from interface 1");
        }
    }

    public class ChildClass : BaseClass
    {
        public void ChildClassMethod()
        {
            Interface1Run();
            Interface2Run();      
        }
    }
    public class Program : ChildClass
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChildClass childclass = new ChildClass();
            childclass.ChildClassMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some explnation

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of Roland Pihlakas's nice solution. This version supports the entire inheritance chain instead of immediate base class. The Invoke method includes additional parameters and there is a void type Invoke for non-function methods.

```
public class BaseClassExplicitInterfaceInvoker<T>
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, MethodInfo> Cache = new Dictionary<string, MethodInfo>();

    MethodInfo FindMethod(string MethodName)
    {
        if (Cache.TryGetValue(MethodName, out var Result)) return Result;

        var BaseType = typeof(T);
        while (Result == null)
        {
            if ((BaseType = BaseType.BaseType) == typeof(object)) break;

            var Methods = BaseType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
            Result = Methods.FirstOrDefault(X => X.IsFinal && X.IsPrivate && (X.Name == MethodName || X.Name.EndsWith("." + MethodName)));
        }

        if (Result != null) Cache.Add(MethodName, Result);

        return Result;
    }

    public void Invoke(T Object, string MethodName, params object[] Parameters) => FindMethod(MethodName).Invoke(Object, Parameters);
    public ReturnType Invoke<ReturnType>(T Object, string MethodName, params object[] Parameters) => (ReturnType)FindMethod(MethodName).Invoke(Object, Parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On option would be to create a base class that doesn't excplicitly implement an interface, and to only implement the interface on the subclass.

```
public class MyBase
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        //Do things
    }
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
    void MethodA();
    void MethodB();
}


public class MySub: MyBase, IMyInterface
{
    public void MethodB()
    {
        //Do things
    }
}
```

Doing this will allow you to access the base classes MethodA without having to implemnet it in MySyb.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, it is not possible without some form of a workaround. Your helper method option can be extended by making the method virtual and then just overriding it in the child classes.

```
interface I
{
    int M();
}

class A : I
{
    int I.M() { return M(); }

    protected virtual int M()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class B : A, I
{
    protected override int M()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't call Explicit interface method in base class,here i solved this issue

I have two interface -> Interface1 and Interface2

```
public interface Interface1
{      
    string method2();      
}

public interface Interface2
{   
    string method22();

}
```

Main class Method

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        class1 cls = new class1();
        string str = cls.method2();
    }
}
```

and my interface implemented class

```
class class1 : Interface1, Interface2
{

    #region Interface1 Members

    public string method2()
    {
        return (this as Interface2).method22();
    }      

    #endregion

    #region Interface2 Members      

    string Interface2.method22()
    {
        return "2";
    }

    #endregion
}
```