# call a base-class explicit interface method in F#

Tags: inheritance, f#, explicit-interface

Ok I derive a type `B` from a base class `A`.
`A` implements `IDisposable` explicit but I have to do additional cleanup in `B`, so I implement `IDisposable` in `B`:

```
interface IDisposable with
    member i.Dispose() =
        // ... additional work
        base.Dispose() // <- want to do but cannot
```

Question is: how to access the Dispose-method from base?

```
(base :> IDisposable).Dispose()
```

yields compiler error: `Unexpected symbol ':>' in expression. Expected '.' or other token.`

Doing something like

```
(i :> IDisposable).Dispose()
```

of course yields a `StackOverflowException` on runtime - so how can I do this? Sorry but never encountered something like this before...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably better off putting your clean-up logic in a virtual method and implementing `IDisposable` only once.

```
type A() =
  abstract Close : unit -> unit
  default __.Close() =
    printfn "Cleaning up A"
  interface System.IDisposable with
    member this.Dispose() = this.Close()

type B() =
  inherit A()
  override __.Close() = 
    printfn "Cleaning up B"
    base.Close()
```

Since there's no `protected` access modifier, you can use a signature file to make `Close` non-public (or mark it `internal`).

The `base` keyword can only be used for member access, not standalone. That's why `base :> IDisposable` doesn't work.

Looking in Reflector, `Dispose` only calls the public `Close` method. So you could re-implement `IDisposable` and call `base.Close()` instead.

You could have this same scenario in C#. Inheritable classes that implement `IDisposable` should provide a way for subclasses to "plug in" to disposal. This is usually done by providing a `protected virtual Dispose(disposing)` overload that's called from `Dispose()`. For whatever reason, `DuplexClientBase` doesn't follow this convention. Perhaps it was deemed unnecessary given that `Dispose` merely forwards to `Close`.

Comment: ok - I might have put this the wrong way - A is not one of my own types (it's a `DuplexClientBase`) - so this is not a solution. And yes I know that you cannot use base this way (the compiler says so much) - the question is HOW do I get to the Dispose of base. For now I solved this by using a public member method to clean up and have the callers clean up by calling this method + dispose but this is only a hack and feels just wrong

Comment: Have you checked if there's an overridable overload of `Dipose`? `protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)` is a common pattern.

Comment: I have not checked explicit but not if MSDN is right: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576169.aspx - I get the feeling that you cannot do this in F# if so can someone confirm this?

Comment: oh - excelent idea - thank you. But still somewhat strange that you cannot to some of the simplest things in F# :(

Comment: yeah - sure you are right (had always thought you coude use base in C# in such a case but have to admit I never tried) - can you include this into your answer so I can mark is as the answer? Thank you!

Comment: You can't make it internal using either a signature file or access modifier if `B` isn't in the same assembly as `A`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do this from C# or any language; explicit interfaces do not allow this.

Comment: thank you for your feedback - indeed never stumpled upon this before - but Daniel already mentioned and I only can mark one answer so *just* +1

Answer (score 0):

Calling base class explicit interface can be done using reflection.

See my answer to a related question about C#: 

[How to call an explicitly implemented interface-method on the base class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044000/193017)

Comment: in your answer there you are using reflection. I did not *explicitly* say so but I don't really want the *hacky* way - but thank you.