# IDbAsyncEnumerable not implemented

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to make a FakeDbContext with a FakeDbSet for unit testing.

But I get the following error (see below). I am extending DbSet so normally IDbAsyncEnumerable should be implemented. And when I implement it, it says that it has no use.

Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't
>   implement
>   IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only
>   sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity
>   Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.

FakeDbSet class:

```
public abstract class FakeDbSet<TEntity> : DbSet<TEntity>, IEnumerable<TEntity>, IQueryable, IDbAsyncEnumerable<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, new()
{
    #region Private Fields
    private readonly ObservableCollection<TEntity> _items;
    private readonly IQueryable _query;
    #endregion Private Fields

    protected FakeDbSet()
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<TEntity>();
        _query = _items.AsQueryable();
    }

    public Expression Expression { get { return _query.Expression; } }

    public Type ElementType { get { return _query.ElementType; } }

    public IQueryProvider Provider { get { return _query.Provider; } }

    public override TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        _items.Add(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public override TEntity Remove(TEntity entity)
    {
        _items.Remove(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public override TEntity Attach(TEntity entity)
    {
        switch (entity.ObjectState)
        {
            case ObjectState.Modified:
                _items.Remove(entity);
                _items.Add(entity);
                break;

            case ObjectState.Deleted:
                _items.Remove(entity);
                break;

            case ObjectState.Unchanged:
            case ObjectState.Added:
                _items.Add(entity);
                break;

            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return entity;
    }

    public override TEntity Create() { return new TEntity(); }

    public override TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() { return Activator.CreateInstance<TDerivedEntity>(); }

    public override ObservableCollection<TEntity> Local { get { return _items; } }

    IEnumerator<TEntity> IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    Type IQueryable.ElementType
    {
        get { return _items.AsQueryable().ElementType; }
    }

    Expression IQueryable.Expression
    {
        get { return _items.AsQueryable().Expression; }
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider
    {
        get { return _items.AsQueryable().Provider; }
    }
```

Here is a gist with the code. In the last file in the gist, that is where the error happens.
[Gist code](https://gist.github.com/ghost606/36718ff9670aad9c4f2e#file-searchdoubtfuls-cs)

Comment: Added a quick and easy way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68103942/661933

Comment: Use:  **using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;**   and remove **using System.Data.Entity;**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your scenario is explicitly mentioned in the link provided with the exception message (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068).  The missing ingredient is the IDbAsyncQueryProvider that you should return from your Provider property.

Just navigate through the link to arrive at [the boilerplate implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async).

Little I can add, I'll just quote the essential phrase:

> In order to use asynchronous queries we need to do a little more work. If we tried to use our Moq DbSet with the GetAllBlogsAsync method we would get the following exception:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. Only sources that implement IDbAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.
>
> In order to use the async methods we need to create an in-memory DbAsyncQueryProvider to process the async query. Whilst it would be possible to setup a query provider using Moq, it is much easier to create a test double implementation in code. The code for this implementation is as follows:
>
> etc...

Comment: I did add the classes given but I don't know how I can connect it with my test. I am not using moq at the moment. I will add all my code to the question. @Hans Passant

Answer (score 302):

In my case the exception was caused by using the wrong `ToListAsync` extension.

It came from:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

instead of

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Changing the namespace fixed the error.

Comment: Can someone pls explain why the error was resolved by changing the namespace?

Comment: @mohammadeunus because there are two different extensions with the name `ToListAsync`. One of them in each namespace that extend different types. [`System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.tolistasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) & there is also [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync?view=efcore-7.0)

Answer (score 22):

I renamed the example test classes from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429#async) to remove the word `Test` since they are useful outside of testing:

- `DbAsyncEnumerable`
- `DbAsyncEnumerator<T>`
- `DbAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity>`

Then I added the extension class below so you can now just do ...

```
var data = new List<Blog> 
{ 
    new Blog { Name = "BBB" }, 
    new Blog { Name = "ZZZ" }, 
    new Blog { Name = "AAA" }, 
}.AsAsyncQueryable();   // <<== new extension method
```

This is not only useful in unit tests but also when you want to implement an `IQueryable<T>` interface that either returns an async database query or in memory data that you can subsequently safely call as `query.ToAsyncArray()`.

```
public static class AsyncQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TElement> AsAsyncQueryable<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(source);
    }

    public static IDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement> AsDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(source);
    }

    public static EnumerableQuery<TElement> AsAsyncEnumerableQuery<TElement>(this IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(source);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TElement> AsAsyncQueryable<TElement>(this Expression expression)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public static IDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement> AsDbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(this Expression expression)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public static EnumerableQuery<TElement> AsAsyncEnumerableQuery<TElement>(this Expression expression)
    {
        return new DbAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat for me; EF 6, MSTest & NSubstitute - testing some code which called a FirstOrDefaultAsync()

Answer (score 7):

Just a note for people using the boilerplate code discussed above from Microsoft, here is a quick helper class that can transform your mocked up data into the async result. Just add to the bottom of the MS code and call with something like

```
var fakeDateAsMockAsyncQueryResult = new MockAsyncData<SomeType>().MockAsyncQueryResult(fakeDataList.AsQueryable());
```

.......

```
internal class MockAsyncData<T> where T : class
{ 
    public Mock<DbSet<T>> MockAsyncQueryResult(IQueryable<T> data)
    {
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

        mockSet.As<IDbAsyncEnumerable<T>>()
            .Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator())
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<T>(data.GetEnumerator()));

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>()
            .Setup(m => m.Provider)
            .Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<T>(data.Provider));

        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        return mockSet;
    }
}
```

It's the same code as in the MS example but generic and reusable from many different unit tests.

Comment: What is TestDbAsyncEnumerator and TestDbAsyncQueryProvider?

Comment: I had the same issue as User441521.  Both TestDbAsyncEnumerator and TestDbAsyncQueryProvider are undefined.

Comment: @PaulGorbas and anyone else wondering. The missing classes *TestDbAsyncEnumerator* and *TestDbAsyncQueryProvider* are provided in the Microsoft guidance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429(v=vs.113).aspx. You'll need to copy the code into your own project.

Answer (score 2):

To solved my **IDbAsyncEnumerable** issue:

1. Changed my project's target from **.NetFramework 4.0** to **.NetFramework 4.5**
2. Reinstalled **EntityFramework 6.1.3** **Nuget package**.
3. At this point, my Visual Studio's IDE **Show Potencial Fixes** advisor, allowed me to reference System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure namespace

> using **System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure**;

Comment: How do you use this?

Comment: Hi @tofutim. Sorry for the late reaction. Are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`DbSet` probably implements `IDbSet` implicitly so that those methods are not available for [interface mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664592(v=vs.71).aspx) in your derived class.

Don't derive from `IDbSet<TEntity>`.

[You cannot call the explicitly implemented interface members of `IDbSet` from a re-implementation of that interface.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976216/how-to-call-an-explicitly-implemented-interface-method-on-the-base-class)

Comment: I fixed the bug but now I am back on the same bug xD I will edit my post with the changed I made.

Comment: btw As you can see I removed the IDbSet implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related but might help some others. If you're using [DelegateCompiler](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler), make sure you're using `DecompileAsync` rather than `Decompile` in the EF packages ([source](https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler#using-with-entityframework-and-other-orms)).

Answer (score 0):

For me i was returning `synchronous queryable`

`return Enumerable.Empty<MyType>().AsQueryable();`

for a method with return a type of `asynchronous queryable`

`_dbConext.MyType.AsQueryable()`

Error:

`"The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IDbAsyncQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations. For more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=287068.",`

**I fixed the problem** by getting rid of this line

`return Enumerable.Empty<MyType>().AsQueryable();`

which does not implement `IDbAsyncQueryProvider`