# Enable testing of IDbAsyncEnumerable in a large database (data first)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to unit test a large database. My queries will use methods like FirstOrDefaultAsync(). This results in an exception of the DbSet does not implement IDbAsyncEnumerable. For the underlying issue, and a potential solution to it, see [IDbAsyncEnumerable not implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296091/idbasyncenumerable-not-implemented).

I am creating my test database as follows:

```
  var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDb>()
       .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: myName)
       .Options;
  return new MyDb(options);
```

But now for the problem -- the solution there involves overriding the DbSet class with a TestDbSet that implements the missing interface IDbAsyncEnumerable. So I need my Db class to return a TestDbSet for all of the entities. The number is large, and furthermore, the db class is often regenerated (database first).

One possibility I noticed is the method

```
 DbContextOptionsBuilder.ReplaceService
```

That certainly looks intriguing -- **is whatever generates the DbSet objects a "service" that one can replace?** If I can tell it to always return a TestDbSet instead of a DbSet, that would solve my problem. But I can't find any documentation of what the "services" are that could be replaced by this method.

Comment: `DbContextOptionsBuilder`? There is no such thing in EF6. And if you are on EF Core, simply use [In-Memory Database Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/).

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag. Fixed, and clarifying question above momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Create partial class of your dbset created by database fitst and implement interface IDbAsyncEnumerable

Comment: It's a Microsoft class in a Microsoft namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using the wrong overload of FirstOrDefaultAsync(). For my particular case, the correct one was the one in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.