# How to call a base function that's an explicit interface implementation?

Tags: c#, explicit-interface

Basic problem (pseudocode):

```
interface ISomethingDoer
{
   void DoSomething();
}

class A: ISomethingDoer
{
   void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething()
   {
      Something.Do();
   }
}

class B: A, ISomethingDoer
{
   void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething()
   {
      if (reason)
      {
         base.DoSomething(); //this does not compile
      }
      SomethingElse.Do();
   }
}
```

Is there any way to make this work without removing the explicit implementation from class `A`?

Comment: Not without reflection.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest changing your base class a little such that `DoSomething` calls a protected method:

```
class A: ISomethingDoer
{
   void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething()
   {
       DoSomethingImpl();
   }

   protected void DoSomethingImpl()
   {
       Something.Do();
   }
}
```

And then in `B` you can call `DoSomethingImpl`:

```
class B: A, ISomethingDoer
{
   void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething()
   {
      if (reason)
      {
         DoSomethingImpl(); //this does compile
      }
      SomethingElse.Do();
   }
}
```

---

The alternative method suggested by [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) is to use reflection:

```
class B: A, ISomethingDoer
{
   void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething()
   {
      if (reason)
      {
         string baseName = $"{typeof(ISomethingDoer).FullName}.{nameof(DoSomething)}";
         MethodInfo baseMethod = this.GetType().BaseType
             .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
             .FirstOrDefault(m => m.IsPrivate && m.IsFinal && m.Name == baseName);
          baseMethod.Invoke(this, new object[0]);
      }
      SomethingElse.Do();
   }
}
```

But I don't like this approach since it uses reflection and is going to be slower. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12044000/3181933) to help me build the reflection solution.

You can use [GetParameters()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters?view=netcore-3.1) if you need to filter different overloads of the method, and you can specify arguments by building an `object[]` array containing them in the same positional order.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't able to call `base` on an interface type, but you could refactor your classes to make this possible.

By moving the content of your method into a `protected` method, you can call it directly by both classes, like this:

```
interface ISomethingDoer
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class A : ISomethingDoer
{
    void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething()
    {
        _DoSomething();
    }

    protected void _DoSomething()
    {
        Something.Do();
    }
}

class B : A, ISomethingDoer
{
    void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething()
    {
        if (reason)
        {
            base._DoSomething();
        }
        SomethingElse.Do();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good basic implementation:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Eat();
}

public class Animal : IAnimal
{
    public void Eat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This Animal is Eating!");
    }
}

public class Shark : Animal
{
    public void Eat(bool useBase)
    {
        if (useBase)
        {
            base.Eat();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Shark is devouring everything with 120840128904 teeth");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quoting the question: _"Is there any way to make this work **without removing the explicit implementation** from class A?"_

Comment: @John did I remove it?

Comment: Yes, you did. An explicit interface implementation looks like `void IAnimal.Eat()`, not `public void Eat()`.

Comment: providing a parameter that indicates how the method should work internally doesn´t seem good to me.

Comment: @John you are right, anyway I wouldn't even like to find in production such implementation, I guess he can take my answer as another approach to solve the problem.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I think the same, I placed it only for the "reason" variable in his example, which could be something even worse

Comment: @Macro I agree. I dislike explicit interfaces generally. They are handy when making fluent interfaces without defining loads of classes though. :-D

Answer (score 0):

I always make private implementation as wrappers to methods.

```
interface ISomethingDoer
{
    void DoSomething();
}

class A : ISomethingDoer
{
    protected void DoSomething()
    {
        Something.Do();
    }
    void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething() => DoSomething();
}

class B : A, ISomethingDoer
{
    protected void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        if (reason)
        {
            base.DoSomething();
        }
        SomethingElse.Do();
    }
    void ISomethingDoer.DoSomething() => DoSomethingElse();
}
```